# Exterior derivative of a 2-form defined by composition of metric with an endomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, exterior-derivative

Im interested in calculating the exterior derivative of a 2-form defined by $\omega(x,y) = g(x,Ay)$ where
$A \in \Gamma(End(T)
)$ is skew and $g$ is some metric.

I hope to reach some coordinate-independent expression involving the covariant derivative of $A$ and possibly the curvature of $g$.

Comment: You can try to use the equality
\begin{align}
d\omega (X,Y,Z) &= X\left(\omega(Y,Z)\right) - Y \left(\omega(X,Z)\right) + Z\left(\omega(X,Y)\right) \\
& \quad -\omega([X,Y],Z) +\omega([X,Z],Y) - \omega([Y,Z],X).
\end{align}
(Together with properties of the Levi-Civita connection). This is totally coordinate-independent

Comment: @Didier Great suggestion!

Comment: Curvature can't appear, because the metric will be differentiated only once. The answer will depend on only $g$, $A$, and $\nabla A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to coordinates, $A$ and $g$ can be written as \begin{align*} A(\partial_k) &= A_k^p\partial_p\\ g(\partial_i,\partial_j) &= g_{ij}. \end{align*} Let $$ A_{jk} = g_{ij}A^i_k. $$ That $A$ is skew (with respect to $g$) means $$A_{jk} = - A_{kj}.$$ Moreover, it is easy to check that $$ \omega(\partial_j,\partial_k) = A_{jk} $$ and therefore $$\omega = A_{jk}\,dx^j\wedge dx^k. $$ So $$ d\omega = \partial_iA_{jk}\,dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k. $$ Now, given a point $x_0$, choose coordinates so that $\partial_ig_{jk}(x_0) = 0$. With respect to those coordinates, $$ \partial_iA_{jk}(x_0) = \nabla_iA_{jk}(x_0). $$ It therefore follows that with respect to *any* coordinates, $$ d\omega = \nabla_iA_{jk}\,dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! using @Didier 's suggestion I also managed to derive the coordinate-free expression: 

$d \omega (X,Y,Z) = g(Y, (\nabla_{X} A) Z ) - g(X, (\nabla_{Y} A) Z) + g(X, \nabla_{Z} A) Y) $

Comment: Yes, I see now that @Didier's approach is easier.